# COMインターフェイス IKsTopologyInfo, IKsControl をC#で使用する方法

Tags: c#, camera, com

現在、C#および.NET FrameworkでUVCカメラのレジスタ値を変更するアプリケーションを作成中です。
C++ではDirectShowの「`IKsTopologyInfo::CreateNodeInstance`」メソッドを使用してインターフェイスにアクセスし、生成したノードオブジェクトに対して「`IUnknown::QueryInterface`」を呼び出して、必要なCOM API（[`IKsControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ksproxy/nn-ksproxy-ikscontrol)）を取得しています。
その後、取得したオブジェクトに対して「[`IKsControl::KsProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ksproxy/nf-ksproxy-ikscontrol-ksproperty)」メソッドを使用することで、「[`KSPROPERTY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/stream/ksproperty-structure)」構造体で設定した値に基づいてプロパティデータの読み書きができました。

C#でのアクセスを調べてみましたがなかなか記事が出てこなかったため、「P/Invoke」で上記のメソッドを呼び出しUVC拡張ユニットと通信しようと考えています。

C#で実現する方法をご存じの方ご教授願います。

##### 追記

C++のソースコードは以下を参考にしています。

- [UVC 拡張ユニットのサンプル アプリケーション - Windows drivers | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-hardware/drivers/stream/sample-application-for-uvc-extension-units)

##### 関連する質問

- [c# - UVCカメラのExtension Unitにデータを送信したい - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/98326)

Comment: "「P/Invoke」で上記のメソッドを呼び出しUVC拡張ユニットと通信しようと考えています。" と "プラットフォームを呼び出さず"  で矛盾しているように思われますが、何を聞かれているのかよく分かりません。C#からCOMを利用する方法を知りたいという事でしょうか？そうであれば、C++で出来ているソースも載せた方がいいと思います。

Comment: 矛盾している点は"プラットフォームを呼び出さず実現したい"が、調べた限りできそうになかったので"現在はプラットフォームを呼び出すことも視野に入れている"という意味です。
紛らわしくて申し訳ございません。

聞きたいことは、COM APIを取得してC#からUVC拡張ユニットとの通信を行う方法です。

Comment: もしかしたらこんなクラス [VideoDeviceController クラス](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/uwp/api/windows.media.devices.videodevicecontroller?view=winrt-22621) の関連で出来るのでは？ {Get/Set}DeviceProperty{ById/ByExtendedId}等のメソッドがあるようです。

Comment: 今回はUWPではなく.NET Frameworkでの開発を目標としているので、紹介いただいたクラスは使用できません。

Comment: この辺の記事を見ると出来そうな感じですが。[超簡単！ WPFなどの.NETのアプリからUWPのAPIを使う～日本語の読み仮名を取得するAPIを題材に](https://codezine.jp/article/detail/10654), [WPFアプリ（.Net Framework）でUWPのAPIを使う](https://qiita.com/FumiyaHr/items/13de3dcbd9b81d9d27f0) BingのCopilotで訊ねてみても出来そうな回答が返ってきています。

Comment: 必要なバッファのサイズを取得するためと、実際に情報を取得するための、2回の呼び出しが必要なのでは？ [解説 - IKsControl::KsProperty メソッド (ksproxy.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ksproxy/nf-ksproxy-ikscontrol-ksproperty#remarks)

Comment: そもそもこのサイトは一問一答が基本なので、追加の質問は別質問を立ててください。COMの件が解決したのであれば、この質問はクローズしてください。

Comment: 確かに2回呼び出す必要があるようでした。

Comment: タイトルに書いてある通り最終的に聞きたかったことはUVC拡張ユニットとの通信方法で、DirectNの追記はそのために必要なことだと思います。
このような場合でも別の質問を立てるべきなのでしょうか。

Comment: はい。本来であれば、このタイトルの質問だと具体性に欠けるので強制クローズ対象です。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions [より焦点を絞る必要がある]をご覧ください。質問の本文である程度焦点を絞れると判断したので回答しましたが、あなたは、質問文を変更して事実上一つの質問で複数の質問を聞こうとしています。これは認められません。

Comment: 今回、削除という結果となり残念です。
できれば、削除を取り消していただけないかと思い、コメント差し上げます。
Q&Aは公開し続けることにより、他の方々にも役立つ可能性が有ります。
また、新たなアプローチや補足的な回答が追加されることもあります。
それが必ずしも質問者さんに必要とは限りませんが、そういった情報も集積して、広く公開し続けるのもこのサイトの大きな目的です。
再考いただければと思います。
参考: [「質問を取り消したいですが削除しても良いですか？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: なお、コメントのやりとりで誤解が有ったかも知れませんので、その点を説明させて下さい。
〔1. 《クローズしてください》というコメント:
これはコメントされた方が表現を誤ったものでしょう。
実際には [クローズ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) や削除は求められていません。
一問一答形式に収めるため、新たに生じた疑問は別の質問として欲しい、というのが伝えたかった事です。
〕
〔2. 《強制クローズ対象》というコメント:
私はまったくクローズ対象では無いと思いますし、他の方からもクローズ票は1票も入っていません。
これは「本文を読めばそうでは無い」というのが本旨であり、表現の強さを誤ったもので以後注意すると、
コメントなさった方から説明いただいています。
〕

Comment: C#への変換を答えることはできるけど、さすがにサンプルコードへのリンクなら気乗りしないです。質問者さんが書いたというC++コードならやるかも。

Comment: C++コードをサンプルとして追記する場合は本質問と別に質問枠をとるべきでしょうか。それとも本文を編集し、追記としてもよろしいのでしょうか。

Comment: 尋ねたい部分、すなわちC++で実現できていてC#で実現できていない部分を追記されるのがよろしいかと。もし、C++全文を掲載してC#で書けととなるようでしたら、質問ではなく開発要求であり開発者を雇うべきかなと思います。

Comment: kunif さんも提示されていますが、多くのWinRTコンポーネントは、UWP専用のGUIコンポーネントを除き、WinFormsやWPFなどのデスクトップ.NETアプリからも使うことができるようになっています。[ExtendedControlAndMetadata](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Camera/tree/master/Samples/ExtendedControlAndMetadata)の公式サンプルでは、WinRT APIを使い、`KSPROPERTY`を経由してカメラデバイスと通信する方法が提示されています。このサンプルコードでは[C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt)を使って実装されたヘルパーライブラリ[CameraKsPropertyHelper](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Camera/tree/master/Samples/Shared/CameraKsPropertyHelper)が使用されています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DirectN](https://github.com/smourier/DirectN)

> Direct Interop code for .NET Framework, .NET Core and .NET 5+ : DXGI, WIC, DirectX 9 to 12, Direct2D, Direct Write, Direct Composition, Media Foundation, WASAPI, CodecAPI, GDI, Spatial Audio, DVD, Windows Media Player, UWP DXInterop, WinUI3, etc.

こちらを使ってみたらどうでしょう？