# C#でIKsTopologyInfo, IKsControlを使用し、UVCカメラのCOM APIを取得する

Tags: c#, camera, usb, com

現在C#および.NET FrameworkでUVCカメラのCOM APIを取得したいと考えております。

C++では下記リンクを参考にDirectShowの`IKsTopologyInfo`と`IKsControl`インターフェイスを使用し、COM APIを取得することができました。

[video streaming - Enumerating UVC Properties items of a property set of a camera - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874790/enumerating-uvc-properties-items-of-a-property-set-of-a-camera)

C#で[DirectShowLib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/)と[DirectN](https://github.com/smourier/DirectN)を使用し同様のことをしたいと考えていますが、インターフェイスへのアクセスやCOM APIの取得ができません。

改善方法をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授お願い致します。

**開発環境:**
Windows 10 (22H2)
Visual Studio 17.8.4
.NET Framework 4.7.2
DirectShowLib 1.0.0
DirectN 1.15.0.2

##### C#

```cs
public Boolean SetValue(DirectShowLib.IBaseFilter pMediaSource, int nodeId)
{
    HRESULT hRet;
    DirectN.IKsTopologyInfo ksTopology;
    Guid iid;
    IntPtr pUnk1;
    IntPtr ppv1;
    object unk;

    pUnk1 = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(pMediaSource, typeof(DirectShowLib.IBaseFilter));
    iid = new Guid("720D4AC0-7533-11D0-A5D6-28DB04C10000");
    ksTopology = pMediaSource as DirectN.IKsTopologyInfo;
    ppv1 = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(ksTopology, typeof(DirectN.IKsTopologyInfo));

    hRet = Marshal.QueryInterface(pUnk1, ref iid, out ppv1);
    if (hRet != 0)
        return false;

    iid = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");

    hRet = ksTopology.CreateNodeInstance((uint)nodeId, iid, out unk);
    if (hRet != 0)
        return false;

    IKsControl ksCnt;
    IntPtr pUnk2;
    IntPtr ppv2;

    pUnk2 = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(GCHandle.Alloc(unk));
    iid = new Guid("28F54685-06FD-11D2-B27A-00A0C9223196");
    ksCnt = unk as IKsControl;
    ppv2 = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(ksCnt, typeof(IKsControl));

    hRet = Marshal.QueryInterface(pUnk2, ref iid, out ppv2);
    if (hRet != 0)
        return false;

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ksCnt);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ksTopology);

    return true;
}
```

##### 関連する質問

- [c# - COMインターフェイス IKsTopologyInfo, IKsControl をC#で使用する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/98103/com%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc%e3%83%95%e3%82%a7%e3%82%a4%e3%82%b9-ikstopologyinfo-ikscontrol-%e3%82%92c%e3%81%a7%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95)

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/98103 と関連する質問のようですが、質問文にその旨記載しておくべきだと思います。また、OSのバージョン、Visual Studioのバージョン、.NET Frameworkのバージョン、サードパーティ製ライブラリのバージョンなど、開発環境に関する情報も詳しく記載してください。ちなみに「DirectShowLib」とは何でしょうか？　「[DirectShow.NET](https://directshownet.sourceforge.net/)」のことでしょうか？

Comment: はい、[DirectShowLib]は[DirectShow.NET]の認識で間違いありません。

Comment: 以前にも指摘しましたが、質問のタイトルは問題となっているポイントを絞って具体的に書いてください。（●●の呼び出しで●●の作成に失敗する、コンパイルエラー●●が発生する等）質問文に、想定する結果、実際の結果、エラーコードも併せて記載した方がよいでしょう。

Comment: また、COMオブジェクトに対して Marshal.FreeHGlobal はまずいので Marshal.ReleaseComObject を使用してください。

Comment: Marshal.ReleaseComObjectの指摘承知しました。
タイトルと質問文に関してですが、記載したC#コードのほとんどが正常に動作していない可能性と複数のエラーが発生しているため、一つに絞るのが難しい状況です。
この場合もすべて記載するべきですか？

Comment: 複数のエラーとはどういう事でしょう？最初の処理がエラーとなっていて、後の処理がうまく動いていないだけとも考えられるので、まず最初のエラーを解消する質問にされてはいかかでしょうか。一つの質問に対して、一つの回答というのが基本になりますので、問題が広範すぎると回答が難しくなります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++言語の

> ```cpp
> hRet = pMediaSource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IKsTopologyInfo), (void**)&ksTopology);
> if (FAILED(hRet))
>     return FALSE;
>
> hRet = ksTopology->CreateNodeInstance(nodeId, __uuidof(IUnknown), (VOID**)&unk);
> if (FAILED(hRet))
>     return FALSE;
>
> hRet = unk->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IKsControl), (VOID**)&ksCnt);
> if (FAILED(hRet))
>     return FALSE;
> ```

に対応するC#言語コードは

```cs
var ksTopology = (DirectShowLib.IKsTopologyInfo)pMediaSource;
ksTopology.CreateNodeInstance(nodeId, typeof(DirectN.IKsControl).GUID, out var unknown);
var ksCnt = (DirectN.IKsControl)unknown;
```

くらいになります。
DirectShowLibもDirectNも内部的には[.NETでのCOM相互運用](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/native-interop/cominterop)という同じ機能を利用しているため、相互に型キャスト可能です。その上で、このCOM相互運用では`型キャスト`がCOMにおける`IUnknown::QueryInterface()`に対応しています。