# 「IKsControl::KsProperty」メソッドの呼び出しで「ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER」エラーが発生する

Tags: c#, camera, usb, com

現在C#および.NET FrameworkでUVCカメラのExtension Unitにデータを送信したいと考えております。

[DirectShowlib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/)と[DirectN](https://github.com/smourier/DirectN)を使用しCOM APIを取得後、`KSIDENTIFIER`構造体でUVCカメラのGuid、送信先アドレス、要求の種類を設定。
`IKsControl::KsProperty`メソッドでデータの送信を行いましたが、「0x800706F8」エラーが発生してしまいました。

エラーを改善し、正常にデータを送信する方法が知りたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

**開発環境**
Windows 10 (22H2)
Visual Studio 17.8.4
.NET Framework 4.7.2
DirectN 1.15.0.2

##### C#

```cs
public const int KSPROPERTY_TYPE_GET = 0x00000001;
public const int KSPROPERTY_TYPE_SET = 0x00000002;
public const int KSPROPERTY_TYPE_TOPOLOGY = 0x10000000;

public Boolean SetValue(DirectShowLib.IBaseFilter pMediaSource, Guid cameraGuid, int nodeId, int propId, int transData)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    
    var ksTopology = (DirectShowLib.IKsTopologyInfo)pMediaSource;
    ksTopology.CreateNodeInstance(nodeId, typeof(DirectN.IKsControl).GUID, out var unknown);
    var ksCnt = (DirectN.IKsControl)unknown;
    
    __struct_ks_2__union_0__struct_0 st;
    st.Set = cameraGuid;
    st.Id = (uint)propId;
    st.Flags = KSPROPERTY_TYPE_SET | KSPROPERTY_TYPE_TOPOLOGY;
    
    KSIDENTIFIER prop = new KSIDENTIFIER();
    prop.__union_0.__field_0 = st;
    
    byte[] data = new byte[16];
    IntPtr propertyData = IntPtr.Zero;
    uint bytesReturned = 0;
    
    data[0] = (byte)(transData & 0xff);
    data[1] = 0;
    propertyData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, propertyData, data.Length);
    
    hr = ksCnt.KsProperty(prop, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(prop), out propertyData, 1, out bytesReturned);  //ここで発生
    
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(propertyData);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ksTopology);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(unknown);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ksCnt);
    
    return true;
}
```

##### 追記

下記のようにPropertyDataとPropertyLengthに0を設定し、バッファサイズを取得しようと試みましたが「0x800706F8」エラーの状況が変わりませんでした。

```cs
propertyData = IntPtr.Zero;
hr = ksCnt.KsProperty(prop, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(prop), out propertyData, 0, out bytesReturned);
//bytesReturned -> 0
```

##### 参考

- [Enumerating UVC Properties items of a property set of a camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874790/enumerating-uvc-properties-items-of-a-property-set-of-a-camera)
- [UVC Extension Unit transfert only one byte of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527127/uvc-extension-unit-transfert-only-one-byte-of-data)

##### 関連する質問

- [c# - C#でIKsTopologyInfo, IKsControlを使用し、UVCカメラのCOM APIを取得する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/98326/c%e3%81%a7ikstopologyinfo-ikscontrol%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e3%81%97-uvc%e3%82%ab%e3%83%a1%e3%83%a9%e3%81%aecom-api%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)
- [c# - COMインターフェイス IKsTopologyInfo, IKsControl をC#で使用する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/98103/com%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc%e3%83%95%e3%82%a7%e3%82%a4%e3%82%b9-ikstopologyinfo-ikscontrol-%e3%82%92c%e3%81%a7%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95)

Comment: この辺の記事からエラーコードを読み解きましょう。[Windowsで表示されるエラーコードの見方](https://ascii.jp/elem/000/001/432/1432965/), [COM エラー コードの構造](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/com/structure-of-com-error-codes), [一般的な HRESULT 値](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/seccrypto/common-hresult-values), [Win32エラーコード一覧](http://ir9.jp/prog/ayu/win32err.htm) 下4桁がWin32エラーの`0x000006F8`なので`ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER 要求された操作に対して与えられたバッファーが無効です。`ということでしょう。どのAPI呼び出しで発生したエラーなのか調べて、そのパラメータに指定したバッファ関連の情報(アドレス・サイズ・初期値など？)を見直してみてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、MicrosoftのIKsControlのドキュメントを確認してみましょう。

[IKsControl::KsProperty メソッド (ksproxy.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ksproxy/nf-ksproxy-ikscontrol-ksproperty)

> ・戻り値
> 成功した場合は NOERROR を返します。それ以外の場合は、エラー コードを返します。
> ・解説
> 特定のプロパティ要求に必要なバッファー サイズを確認するには、 PropertyData を NULL に設定し、 DataLength を 0 に設定して、このメソッドを呼び出すことができます。 メソッドは HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_MORE_DATA) を返し、 BytesReturned には必要なバッファーのサイズが含まれます。

という事なので、解説通りに最初にプロパティ情報に必要なバッファのサイズを受け取る必要があるんじゃないでしょうか。
ちなみに、["0x800706F8" hresult](https://www.google.com/search?q=%220x800706F8%22%20hresult) で検索すると、下記のページが引っかかりました。

[FACILITY_WIN32](https://www.hresult.info/FACILITY_WIN32)

> 0x800706F8 - ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER

直訳すると、無効なユーザーバッファ、と訳わからないですが、バッファが足りてない的な雰囲気は受けますね。

Comment: USBでのデータ通信を行う際、書き込む先のアドレスに対し先に次に送るデータのバイト数を確保する必要があるそうですがそういうことでしょうか？
それとも、プロパティ要求に必要なバイト数を`PropertyData `にNULL、`DataLength `に0を設定し取得後、データを送ることでできるのでしょうか。
また、足りていないバッファとは`PropertyData`という認識で会っていますか？

Comment: PropertyDataのサイズでしょうね。今16byte決め打ちでやってるようですが、多分これがまずいんでしょう。KsPropertyをバッファのサイズ取得、実際のプロパティ情報取得とで二回呼ぶ必要があるんじゃないでしょうか。取得したバッファサイズを元にAllocHGlobalし、そのサイズを渡せばうまくいくかもしれません。（試せる環境がないので、確信はないです）

Comment: 追記について確認したいのですが、bytesReturned には値は何も格納されなかったでしょうか？また、以前の質問でC++のサンプルソースを載せておられましたが、C++では正常に処理は完了したのでしょうか？正常に完了していた場合、propのサイズはC#とC++の時で差異はありませんか？

Comment: bytesReturnedは0でした。C++ではNodeIdを設定するため`KSP_NODE`を使用しています。そのためC++のpropサイズは32byteです。

Comment: C++とC#で違うものを設定しているんですね。エラーがC#特有（呼び出し方や構造体定義のミス等に起因するもの）の現象なのか、単純に引数の構造体に設定する値が間違っているのかを切り分けた方がいいかもしれません。

Comment: もしかすると`KSIDENTIFIER`へGuidやAdrsを設定するところが間違っている可能性があるのですが、特にエラーは出ていません。何か正常に設定できているかの確認方法をご存じでしょうか。

Comment: 申し訳ないですが、私にはちょっとわからないです。Microsoftのドキュメントにサンプルでもあればいいんですけど。指定するフラグ KSPROPERTY_TYPE_TOPOLOGY からググってみて、ヒットしたサンプルソース等を片っ端から試してみるしかないかもしれませんね。

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff564262(v=vs.85) を見ると、KSPROPERTY_TYPE_TOPOLOGYの場合はKSIDENTIFIERではなくKSP_NODEを渡すのでは。KSP_NODEのノードIDってのが何なのかはよく知りませんが。

Comment: 第1引数に`KSP_NODE`をポインタとして設定する必要がありますが、`ref`にポインタを設定することができない？ということと、`KSP_NODE`から`KSIDENTIFIER`にキャストできませんでした。

Comment: ref prop.Property みたいな感じで渡せばよさそうです

Comment: `KSP_NODE`として渡したいのでref prop.Propertyのサイズに`KSP_NODE`を渡すと、「ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION」となります。ですが`KSIDENTIFIER`を渡すと「ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER」になるかつ、`KSP_NODE`として渡せません。

Comment: エラーコードが変わったので、なんか一歩進んだような気もしますね。サイズはKSP_NODEでよさそうです。