# 「IKsControl::KsProperty」メソッドの呼び出しで「ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION」エラーが発生する

Tags: c#, camera, usb, com

現在C#および.NET FrameworkでUVCカメラのExtension Unitにデータを送信したいと考えております。

[DirectShowlib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/)と[DirectN](https://github.com/smourier/DirectN)を使用しCOM APIを取得後、`KSP_NODE`構造体でUVCカメラのGuid、送信先アドレス、要求の種類を設定。
`IKsControl::KsProperty`メソッドでデータの送信を行いましたが、「ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION」エラーが発生してしまいました。

エラーを改善し、正常にデータを送信する方法が知りたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

**開発環境**
Windows 10 (22H2)
Visual Studio 17.8.4
.NET Framework 4.7.2
DirectN 1.15.0.2

##### C#

```cs
public const int KSPROPERTY_TYPE_GET = 0x00000001;
public const int KSPROPERTY_TYPE_SET = 0x00000002;
public const int KSPROPERTY_TYPE_TOPOLOGY = 0x10000000;

public Boolean SetValue(DirectShowLib.IBaseFilter pMediaSource, Guid cameraGuid, int nodeId, int propId, int transData)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    
    var ksTopology = (DirectShowLib.IKsTopologyInfo)pMediaSource;
    ksTopology.CreateNodeInstance(nodeId, typeof(DirectN.IKsControl).GUID, out var unknown);
    var ksCnt = (DirectN.IKsControl)unknown;
    
    __struct_ks_2__union_0__struct_0 st;
    st.Set = cameraGuid;
    st.Id = (uint)propId;
    st.Flags = KSPROPERTY_TYPE_SET | KSPROPERTY_TYPE_TOPOLOGY;
    
    KSP_NODE prop = new KSP_NODE();
    prop.Property.__union_0.__field_0 = st;
    prop.NodeId = (uint)nodeId;
    
    byte[] data = new byte[16];
    IntPtr propertyData = IntPtr.Zero;
    uint bytesReturned = 0;
    
    data[0] = (byte)(transData & 0xff);
    data[1] = 0;
    propertyData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, propertyData, data.Length);
    
    hr = ksCnt.KsProperty(ref prop.Property, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<KSP_NODE>(), out propertyData, 1, out bytesReturned);
    
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(propertyData);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ksCnt);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(unknown);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ksTopology);
    
    if (hr != 0)
        return false;
    
    return true;
}
```

##### 参考

- [Enumerating UVC Properties items of a property set of a camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874790/enumerating-uvc-properties-items-of-a-property-set-of-a-camera)
- [UVC Extension Unit transfert only one byte of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527127/uvc-extension-unit-transfert-only-one-byte-of-data)

##### 関連する質問

- [c# - C#でIKsTopologyInfo, IKsControlを使用し、UVCカメラのCOM APIを取得する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/98326/c%e3%81%a7ikstopologyinfo-ikscontrol%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e3%81%97-uvc%e3%82%ab%e3%83%a1%e3%83%a9%e3%81%aecom-api%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)
- [c# - COMインターフェイス IKsTopologyInfo, IKsControl をC#で使用する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/98103/com%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc%e3%83%95%e3%82%a7%e3%82%a4%e3%82%b9-ikstopologyinfo-ikscontrol-%e3%82%92c%e3%81%a7%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95)
- [c# - 「IKsControl::KsProperty」メソッドの呼び出しで「ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER」エラーが発生する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/98348/ikscontrolksproperty-%e3%83%a1%e3%82%bd%e3%83%83%e3%83%89%e3%81%ae%e5%91%bc%e3%81%b3%e5%87%ba%e3%81%97%e3%81%a7-error-invalid-user-buffer-%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c%e7%99%ba%e7%94%9f%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

結論から言うとDirectNは実装が壊れていて、`IKsControl::KsProperty`メソッドでデータを渡すことができません。

[`IKsControl::KsProperty`メソッド](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ksproxy/nf-ksproxy-ikscontrol-ksproperty)の本来の定義は

```
HRESULT KsProperty(
  [in]      PKSPROPERTY Property,
  [in]      ULONG       PropertyLength,
  [in, out] LPVOID      PropertyData,
  [in]      ULONG       DataLength,
  [in, out] ULONG       *BytesReturned
);
```

となっていて`PropertyData`引数は`[in, out]`とされています。対して、 [DirectNの実装](https://github.com/smourier/DirectN/blob/9f16c0ec46698bc1d28d2103a21edf4f46f179fc/DirectN/DirectN/Generated/IKsControl.cs#L10-L11)では

```
[PreserveSig]
HRESULT KsProperty(/* [in] */ ref KSIDENTIFIER Property, /* [in] */ uint PropertyLength, /* [out][in] */ out IntPtr PropertyData, /* [in] */ uint DataLength, /* [out] */ out uint BytesReturned);
```

`PropertyData`引数はC#言語における`out`とされています。

このため`KSPROPERTY_TYPE_GET`でデータを受け取ることはできますが、`KSPROPERTY_TYPE_SET`でデータを渡すことができません。
他のライブラリを使うか、ご自身で実装するかどちらかを選択する必要があります。